# Error while trying to save cookies from Python and selenium

Tags: python

I need to save cookies derived from selenium. I am using cookiestxt's MozillaCookieJar, but whenever I am trying use set_cookie method, it's giving errors.

```
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\cookielib.py", line 1643, in set_cookie
    if cookie.domain not in c: c[cookie.domain] = {}
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'domain'
Process terminated with an exit code of 1

cookies = [{u'domain': u'.youtube.com', u'name': u'YSC', u'value': u'3IWrNKWSA4M', u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': True, u'secure': False}, {u'domain': u'.youtube.com', u'secure': False, u'value': u'f1=50000000&al=en-GB', u'expiry': 1536214030.209859, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'name': u'PREF'}, {u'domain': u'.youtube.com', u'secure': False, u'value': u'unLb9EHXNoE', u'expiry': 1536214005.088592, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': True, u'name': u'VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE'}, {u'domain': u'.youtube.com', u'secure': False, u'value': u'nAVyIaZNvcjbaoQmU3Klp29Qbg-XUTcXVl--AQaUVNxBxafNdvqF6UalvF-XxI7tFZC9VQ.', u'expiry': 1578248049.22749, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'name': u'SID'}, {u'domain': u'.youtube.com', u'secure': False, u'value': u'XeYri988Qxz95x0C/AKhEa472x1OLAenvb', u'expiry': 1578248049.227637, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'name': u'APISID'}, {u'domain': u'.youtube.com', u'secure': True, u'value': u'A6qerdAIT_-5_TnPL', u'expiry': 1578248049.227601, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': True,
 u'name': u'SSID'}, {u'domain': u'.youtube.com', u'secure': False, u'value': u'AxLIfhQzeMb-JVHvW', u'expiry': 1578248049.227563, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': True, u'name': u'HSID'}, {u'domain': u'.youtube.com', u'secure': True, u'value': u'GrFiuZaX0jrP5xNx/ApjqMj4RLR92qxyaC', u'expiry': 1578248049.227671, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': False, u'name': u'SAPISID'}, {u'domain': u'.youtube.com', u'secure': False, u'value': u'AFmmF2swRgIhAMgj-IZmcAcrW4cm--wm4Mwb_PRnN8sMV3d7sNilw2jyAiEA1QTRmjDEqkVzdK4k6sR4gJGlYQD11aqK11cw_dLUuHQ:QUQ3MjNmeThkM1V3SlBQNFplZkNaVk9kUnNHazhCczc0NmFQZ2htVTVUVk5JWDdkWGxGdjN2blhzWGxzZ3JsSzViZkNWemlocVZzMlpXRVN1OHJHNmxmWFR5cHktUnJfb1poR1FXTzhpUzhBWURJX3JZaHByUFdkeS05cHNaUGN6RWFtMlJZTTBfLUJxcGVZUUQyTDNtcGpYUHZlVUdVQXlxTjZiVjhuQ0x2a29maTFCU2RZaWlj', u'expiry': 1578248049.942557, u'path': u'/', u'httpOnly': True, u'name': u'LOGIN_INFO'}]


from cookiestxt import MozillaCookieJar

cookie_file = "cookies.txt"
cj = MozillaCookieJar("cookies.txt")
for cookie in cookies:
  cj.set_cookie(cookie)
cj.save(ignore_discard=True, ignore_expires=True)
```